# Regex not select word with character at the end

Tags: regex

I have a simple question.
I need a regular expression to match a hexdecimal number without colon at the end.
For example:

```
0x85af6b9d: 0x00256f8a ;some more interesting code
// dont match 0x85af6b9d: at all, but match 0x00256f8a
```

My expression for hexdecimal number is `0[xX][0-9A-Fa-f]{1,8}`

Version with `(?!:)` is not possible, because it will just match `0x85af6b9` (because of the `{1,8}` token)
Using a `$` also isn't possible - there can be more numbers than one

Thanks!

Comment: just throw in a dollar, `0[xX][0-9A-Fa-f]{1,8}$`, that means an end of string

Comment: @nicael oh im sorry, i forgot there can be more code after that. Because of that, the `$` character is not the solution

Comment: @Cubix48 it appeared to be working! Please add it as a answer, so anyone can use it. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do so:

```
0[xX][0-9A-Fa-f]{1,8}(?![0-9A-Fa-f:])
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/F5wSX7/1).

---

We use a negative lookahead to match all hexadecimal numbers without `:` at the end. Because of `{1,8}`, it is also necessary to ensure that the entire hexadecimal number is correctly matched. We therefore reuse the character set (`[0-9A-Fa-f]`) to ensure that the number does not continue.